# Connect to Oracle DB with Java

Tags: java, database, oracle, connection

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB hosted by the faculty.
Given information:

```
host: bazi.finki.ukim.mk
port: 1521
sid: ORCL
user: xxx
pass: xxx
```

here is the code:

```
try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@bazi.finki.ukim.mk:1521:ORCL","user","pass");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I get **"IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"**

Also i want to mention that, every group (by the way, this is for project) have workspace... also protected with username and password, even if I can connect into the database, how can i connect to the workspace?

...And also, they wrote that there need to be created tunnel with Putty, is that necessary and how to create it?

Comment: Check for a solution of your problem [here](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2011/08/network-adapter-could-not-establish.html)

Comment: are you able to connect using sql client?

Comment: Sql client? MySql Workbench, tried i am not sure if i am doing something wrong or i can't really connect.

Answer (score 0):

This is from http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC

There are 2 URL syntax, old syntax which will only work with SID and the new one with Oracle service name.

Old syntax 
 jdbc:oracle:thin:@[HOST][:PORT]:SID

New syntax 
 jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE

Also note that these 2 lines are unnecessary

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
```

DriverManager will automatically detect the necessary driver by url, see API